# What is the characters style in these Japanese games called?

Tags: style-identification, modeling, character-styles, character-design

These are screenshots from *Harvest Moon* and *Trails from the Sky*. I'm trying to find tutorials or something similar to help me learn to create characters of this style, but I don't know what to search for.

What is the name for this style of character?

[image: Harvest Moon 64]
[image: Trails in the sky: the legend of heroes]

Comment: Not exactly sure what your scope is. But if we're looking for the lowest common denominator between the two pictures above I'd say the style is manga, both hinting at chibi styles. That's still very, very broad, are you looking for something more specific? What exactly about the characters is it that you find similar?

Comment: They do look sorta like chibi's but still different. i think they are 3d models when comparing to 2d models i have seen. plus the colors seem do have a fuzz look to me. those two points and their general character look, look the similar to me. except that the bottom game is newer by many years ( about 12 years newer) which is got some upgrades involving details.

Comment: Im looking for a way to learn how to make them the same "way" (modeling software may be different). i hope you understand me. FYI- i am no expert in 3d modeling characters.

Comment: I'd call it 'little people with big heads' style.

Comment: Well, I can't really help you nail what style this is any more than I have. I think you'll have to track down whoever the artists behind the originals are as it might be specific to them. In any case, learning how to draw/model similar characters is a matter of 1) learning the software to do it and 2) copying till you get it right. It could be that there is some super specific tutorial for it somewhere but the closest I think you'll get in that regard is a "how to draw chibi characters" guide. From there you're on your own.

Comment: [Weebles](http://www.waece.org/jyj/imagenes/weebles4_g.jpg) with feet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw these big headed characters?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/how-to-draw-these-big-headed-characters) which also asks for both the name and drawing tips of an almost-identical style

Answer (score 0):

The original 2D manga / anime style is called 'Super Deformed' ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_deformed)) or 'chibi' ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chibi_%28term%29)). As these examples are 3D or faux 3D*, I guess your best bet is '3D chibi' or '3D super deformed'.

*As far as I remember, Falcom usually employs pseudo-3D models in games of this generation and genre. The models are created, but are only used as a basis for the creation of the necessary sprites.